# Does SAS Proc SQL ever use an index when merging

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, sas

Consider the following (admittedly long) example.

The sample code creates two data sets, data one with "key" variables i,j,k and data two with key variables j,k and a "value" variable x. I'd like to merge these two data sets as efficiently as possible. Both of the data sets are indexed with respect to j and k: the index for the first data should not be needed but it's there anyway.

Proc SQL does not use the index in the data two, which I suppose would be the case if the data were in a relational database. Is this just a limitation of the query optimizer I have to accept?

**EDIT:** The answer to this question is yes, SAS can use an index to optimize a PROC SQL join. In the following example, the relative sizes of the data sets matters: If you modify the code so that data two becomes relatively larger than data one, index will be used. Whether the data sets are sorted or not, does not matter.

```
* Just to control the size of the data;
%let j_max=10000;

* Create data sets;
data one;
    do i=1 to 3;
        do j=1 to &j_max;
            do k=1 to 4;
                if ranuni(0)<0.9 then output;
            end;
        end;
    end;
run;

data two;
    do j=1 to &j_max;
        do k=1 to 4;
            x=ranuni(0);
            if ranuni(0)<0.9 then output;
        end;
    end;
run;

* Create indices;
proc datasets library=work nolist;
    modify one;
    index create idx_j_k=(j k);
    modify two;
    index create idx_j_k=(j k) / unique;
run;quit;

* Test the use of an index for the other data set:
* Log should display "INFO: Index idx_j_k selected for WHERE clause optimization.";
options msglevel=i;
data _null_;
    set two(where=(j<100));
run;

* Merge the data sets with proc sql - no index is used;
proc sql;
    create table onetwo as
    select
        one.*,
        two.x
    from one, two
    where
        one.j=two.j and
        one.k=two.k;
quit;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be comparing apples and oranges. For the join you do with `proc sql`, the index may not help because the observations are already ordered by j and k and there are faster ways to do "merging" than using indices.

For the subsetting you do with the `data _null_` step, on the other hand, an index on `j` would surely help. If you do the same subsetting with the `proc sql`, you will see that it *is* using the index.

```
proc sql;
  select * from two where j < 100;
quit;
/* on log
INFO: Index idx_j_k selected for WHERE clause optimization.
*/
```

By the way, you can use the undocumented `_method` option to examine how `proc sql` executes your query. On my sas 9.2 on windows, it reports that it is doing what is called a "hash join":

```
proc sql _method;
  create table onetwo as
  select
    one.*,
    two.x
  from one, two
  where
    one.j=two.j and
    one.k=two.k;
quit;

/* on log
NOTE: SQL execution methods chosen are:

  sqxcrta
      sqxjhsh
          sqxsrc( WORK.ONE )
          sqxsrc( WORK.TWO )
*/
```

See Paul Kent's [Tech note](http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts553.html) for more information .

Comment: Thanks, especially for the query plan trick. +1. The note you linked to says that Proc SQL can use an index, which is good news. I'll try randomizing the order of the observations to see if I can get the optimizer to choose the index.